# How to skip starting 2 words from a string in c#

Tags: c#

How to ignore the first 2 words of a string

like:

```
String x = "hello world this is sample text";
```

in this the first two words are hello world, so i want to skip them, but next time
maybe the words will not be the same, like maybe they become, "Hakuna Matata", but the program should also skip them.

P.S : don't not suggest remove characters it won't work here i guess, because we don't know what is the length of these words, we just want to skip the first two words. and print the rest.

Comment: find the second space and get whats left

Comment: Substring from the second index of the space character to the end of the string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
   String x = "hello world this is sample text";

   var y = string.Join(" ", x.Split(' ').Skip(2));
```

It will split string by spaces, skip two elements then join all elements into one string.

**UPDATE:**

If you have extra spaces than first remove extra spaces and remove words:

```
String x = "hello world this is sample text";
x =  Regex.Replace(x, @"\s+", " ");
var y = string.Join(" ", x.Split(' ').Skip(2));
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, to avoid extra spaces as suggested by Dai (in below comment) I used [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) with StringSplitOptions:

```
String x = "hello       world       this is      sample text";
var y = string.Join(" ", x.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(i => i.Trim()).Skip(2));
```

Comment: The default behaviour of `String.Split(Char)` will result in empty elements if there are sequential matching characters, and using `' '` will only match space characters. I suggest using `String.Split(null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead (which matches all whitespace elements, and doesn't include duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `IndexOf` because it won't help you in the case of consecutive whitespace characters, and using `String.Split(null)` with `String.Join` is inefficient. You could do this using a regex or FSM parser:

```
Int32 startOfSecondWord = -1;

Boolean inWord = false;
Int32 wordCount = 0;
for( int = 0; i < input.Length; i++ ) {
    Boolean isWS = Char.IsWhitespace( input[i] );
    if( inWord ) {
        if( isWS ) inWord = false;
    }
    else {
        if( !isWS ) {
            inWord = true;
            wordCount++;

            if( wordCount == 2 ) {
                startOfSecondWord = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if( startOfSecondWord > -1 ) return input.Substring( startOfSecondWord );
```

Comment: @Andrew It isn't complicated if you're already familiar with state-machine construction, though I appreciate it looks intimidating at first-glance. An advantage of this approach is pure speed: there are zero internal allocations and it runs in `O(n)` time without even traversing the whole string until the `Substring` call.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Regular Expression should do it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "hello world this is sample text";
      string pattern = @"(\w+\s+){2}(.*)";
      string replacement = "$1";
      Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
      string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

      Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
      Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);                             
   }
}
```